# Java escape HTML

Tags: java, html, escaping

currently I use `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils escapeHtml()` to escape unwanted HTML tags in my Strings but then I realized it escapes characters with accents to `&something;,` too, which I don't want.

Do you know any solution for escaping HTML tags but leave my special (well, for some people, they are normal here ;]) letters as they are?

Thanks in advance!

balázs

Comment: `&something;` will be converted to `&amp;something;` -- do you want character '&' not to be escaped? Most usual cases a user enters the symbol that `&something;` stands for, in UI. and escapeHTML just converts that special character to equivalent HTML entity.

Comment: I mean á gets converted to &aacute; which I don't want. I don't want letters to be escaped at all...everything else, yes.

Comment: What do you need to escape HTML for? For JSP?

Comment: Almost, JSF. Do you have any other idea how to prevent users using tags in comments? I have to enable <br/> though, that's why I have to use escape false in the output tags.

Comment: +50 bounty: Please try to give an answer closer to the original question, an escaping function wich will not hurt UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
StringUtils.replaceEach(str, new String[]{"&", "\"", "<", ">"}, new String[]{"&amp;", "&quot;", "&lt;", "&gt;"})
```

Comment: [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) also recommends `'` and `/`.

Comment: Which version of StringUtils is that? I have one in commons-lang-2.2 but no replaceEach method. Not critical though, that's actually easy to implement what you recommened. I would have like an out-of-box solution though :-/

Comment: what about `® ¶ © ½ æ ÷ §`  and the rest of the shebang found at http://arnspublishing.com/QuickRef/ISO8859.html  ?? =)  That replace each is a disater waiting to happen!

Comment: yeah but that's exactly what I did NOT want :) correct me if I'm wrong but I don't know any HTML tags like <§> :P

Comment: @ppumkin, please explain further.

Comment: @pingw33n, I have tried importing `org.springframework.util.StringUtils`, `org.apache.soap.util.StringUtils`, `org.apache.axis.utils.StringUtils`, and `com.ibm.wsdl.util.StringUtils`, and none of them have `StringUtils.replaceEach()`. What are you importing to have access to this method? They seem to have a `.replace()` however.

Comment: @MatthewDoucette it's `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils`: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Comment: what if clients say that he wants &lt; as &lt; only?

Comment: As @EtienneNeveu mentionned you MUST read http://wonko.com/post/html-escaping, it all depends on the context

Answer (score 21):

If it's for Android, use `TextUtils.htmlEncode(String)` instead.

Answer (score 9):

This looks very good to me:

[org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml(java.lang.String)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml%28java.lang.String%29)

By asking XML, you will get XHTML, which is good HTML.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a version that replaces the six significant characters as recommended by [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). This is suitable for HTML content elements like `<textarea>...</textarea>`, but not HTML attributes like `<input value="...">` because the latter are often left unquoted.

```
StringUtils.replaceEach(text,
        new String[]{"&", "<", ">", "\"", "'", "/"},
        new String[]{"&amp;", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&quot;", "&#x27;", "&#x2F;"});
```

Comment: Thanks! Adapted for another solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75355474/3196753.  I chose to declare the characters as `static final` for performance.  I also replaced the hex markup with human-readable replacements.

Answer (score 6):

I know is too late to adding my comment, but perhaps the following code will be helpful:

```
public static String escapeHtml(String string) {
    StringBuilder escapedTxt = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        char tmp = string.charAt(i);
        switch (tmp) {
        case '<':
            escapedTxt.append("&lt;");
            break;
        case '>':
            escapedTxt.append("&gt;");
            break;
        case '&':
            escapedTxt.append("&amp;");
            break;
        case '"':
            escapedTxt.append("&quot;");
            break;
        case '\'':
            escapedTxt.append("&#x27;");
            break;
        case '/':
            escapedTxt.append("&#x2F;");
            break;
        default:
            escapedTxt.append(tmp);
        }
    }
    return escapedTxt.toString();
}
```

enjoy!

Comment: You should use [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Wicket, use:

```
import org.apache.wicket.util.string.Strings;
...
CharSequence cs = Strings.escapeMarkup(src);
String str =      Strings.escapeMarkup(src).toString();
```