# Apache StringUtils vs Java implementation of replace()

Tags: java, replace, apache-stringutils

What would be the difference between Java 1.4.2's implementation of replace, and Apache 2.3's implementation? Is there a performance gain one over another?

[Java 1.4.2 replace](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

[Apache 2.3 replace](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're asking about an ancient Java version?

Comment: Hi Jochim, im stucked with an ancient Java version i must maintain. :(

Comment: Note that `String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` uses regexp internally. :( See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228992/commons-lang-stringutils-replace-performance-vs-string-replace

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `String.replace()` method you linked to takes two `char` values, so it only ever replaces on character with another (possibly multiple times, 'though).

The `StringUtils.replace()` method on the other hand takes `String` values as the search string and replacement, so it can replace longer substrings.

The comparable method in Java would be [`replaceAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). `replaceAll()` is likely to be slower than the `StringUtils` method, because it supports regular expressions and thus introduces the overhead of compiling the search string first and running a regex search.

Note that Java 5 introduced [`String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) which does the same thing as `StringUtils.replace(String,String)` (except that it throws a `NullPointerException` if any of its arguments are `null`). Note that `CharSequence` is an interface implemented by `String`, so you can use plain old `String` objects here.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that java.lang.String.replaceAll(...) uses regex and it is slow. The algorithm used by StringUtils.replace(...) is far superior and outperforms replaceAll()

Comment: @JoachimSauer, the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4874768/910201 mentions `.replaceEach()`, but where is it coming from? I do not have access to such a method and I've tried importing `org.springframework.util.StringUtils`, `org.apache.soap.util.StringUtils`, `org.apache.axis.utils.StringUtils`, and `com.ibm.wsdl.util.StringUtils`.

Comment: @MatthewDoucette: the answer is in the comments of the answer you linked to: Apache Commons-Lang `StringUtils` since Version 2.4.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Compare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(""); // Overhead of static class initialization for StringUtils
        String key = "0 abcdefghijklmno" + Character.toString('\n') + Character.toString('\r');

        String key1 = replace1(key);
        String key2 = replace2(key);
    }


    private static String replace1(String key) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        key = StringUtils.replaceChars(key, ' ', '_');
        key = StringUtils.replaceChars(key, '\n', '_');
        key = StringUtils.replaceChars(key, '\r', '_');
        long end = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.println("Time taken : " + end);
        return key;
    }

    public static String replace2(String word) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        char[] charArr = word.toCharArray();

        int length = charArr.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (charArr[i] == ' ' || charArr[i] == '\n' || charArr[i] == '\r') {
                charArr[i] = '_';
            }
        }

        String temp = new String(charArr);
        long end = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.println("Time taken : " + end);
        return temp;
    }
}
```

> Time taken : 6400
>
> Time taken : 5888

Times are almost the same!

I've edited the code to drop out overheads of `replace2` which were not because of JDK implementation.

Answer (score 2):

1.4.2 replaces operates only with `char` arguments whereas the Apache 2.3 one takes in strings.

Answer (score 1):

- `String.replace(char, char)` can't replace whole strings
- you can have `null` values with `StringUtils.replace(..)`.

`String.replace(CharSequence s1, CharSequence s2)` will do the same thing if the first string is not-null. Otherwise it will throw a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

Apache's is quite a bit faster, if I recall correctly. Recommended.

Comment: how is it faster? Do you have benchmark or algorithm analysis?

Comment: I used it in a project after having done benchmarks, yes. I no longer have them though. Thinking about it, if it wasn't better, why would they develop it? Who's going to add a slower `replace()` option to the String Utils project? :-)

Comment: in 1.4.2 there wasn't a `String.replace(string, string)`. So it was needed in commons. Then 1.5 added it.

Comment: Fair enough; my answer is based on having tested Java 6 string replacement generally against StringUtils string replacement, in which StringUtils fared substantially better.

Comment: I think it was 30% - 50% faster, quite impressive. Was nearly 18 months ago though so I might be wildly out!

Answer (score 0):

To replace a string character with another string using `StringUtil.Replace`, I tried following and it's working fine for me to replace multiple string values from a single string.

```
String info = "[$FIRSTNAME$]_[$LASTNAME$]_[$EMAIL$]_[$ADDRESS$]";

String replacedString = StringUtil.replace(info, new String[] { "[$FIRSTNAME$]","[$LASTNAME$]","[$EMAIL$]","[$ADDRESS$]" }, new String[] { "XYZ", "ABC" ,"abc@abc.com" , "ABCD"});
```

This will replace the String value of info with newly provided value...