# What is the time complexity or Big O notation for "str.replace()" built In function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, big-o

I am confused if the time complexity for `str.replace()` function is O(n) or O(1), for example:

```
var str = "Hello World";
str = str.replace("Hello", "Hi");
console.log(str);
//===> str = "Hi World"
```

Is it always the same answer or does it depend on what we replace?
Any thoughts or helpful links?!

Comment: Are you sure that the return value of `str.replace("Hi")`?

Comment: the definition is `string.replace(searchvalue, newvalue)`

Comment: sorry I've just edited it@ibrahimmahrir

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: I think it's implementation-dependent. It could be different for V8, Rhino, and Nashorn.

Comment: @TaioliFrancesco I know the definition, just forgot the first parameter, what about time complexity?

Comment: thanks I'll read it @devlincarnate

Comment: It depends *a lot* on what you replace. In your example, the search string is found in the first index…

Comment: What is `n`? There are at least three inputs to the call.

Comment: @Bergi take a look at this https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

Comment: @ZainabHammami Maybe that guide is *too* simple for beginners… Sure, `n` is the "*size of the input data set*" as that article puts it (but fails to be explicit about it), but now I am asking you how do you measure the size of your input(s)?

Comment: @Bergi I don't think I understand your questions, if you were asking about `str.replace()` then it accepts only 2 parameters

Comment: @ZainabHammami `str1.replace(str2, str3)` - the `this` value is an implicit parameter :-P

Answer (score 8):

Firstly it should be

```
str = str.replace("Hello", "Hi");
```

Secondly,

searching a substring inside a string can be done in linear time using KMP algorithm which is the most efficient.
Replacing in the worst case will take linear time as well.

So overall time complexity: **O(n)**

Here **n** is dependent on the string `str`. 
In the worst case it will end up traversing the whole string and still not find the searchValue given to the replace function.

Comment: What is `n`? There are at least three inputs to the call.

Comment: `n` is dependent on the string in which the search is done. In the worst case it will end up traversing the whole string and still not find the value to be searched

Answer (score 5):

It's definitely not O(1) ([comparison of string searching algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm)) , but ECMAScript 6 [doesn't dictate the search algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.replace):

> Search string for the first occurrence of searchString and let pos be the index within string of the first code unit of the matched substring and let matched be searchString. If no occurrences of searchString were found, return string.

So it depends on the implementation.

> Is it always the same answer or does it depend on what we replace?

Generally, it will be slower for longer search strings. How much slower is implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

You'll really have to look into implementation details for a complete answer. But to start there's V8's [runtime-strings.cc](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/runtime/runtime-strings.cc) and [builtins-string-gen.cc](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/builtins/builtins-string-gen.cc). It's a deep dive--and I don't know c++, so I'm not entirely sure if I'm even looking at the right files, but they seem to use different approaches depending on the size of the needle and the depth of recursion needed to build a search tree.

For example, in *builtins-string-gen.cc* there's a block under `ES6 #sec-string.prototype.replace` that checks if the `search_string` has a length of 1, and if the `subject_string` length is greater than 255 (`0xFF`). When those conditions are true it looks like `Runtime_StringReplaceOneCharWithString` in *runtime-strings.cc* is called which in turn will try calling `StringReplaceOneCharWithString` first with a tree-traversable `subject_string`.

If that search hits the recursion limit, the runtime makes another call to `StringReplaceOneCharWithString` but this time with a flattened `subject_string`.

So, my partially educated guess here is you're always looking at some kind of linear time. Possibly **O(mn)** when hitting the recursion limit and doing a follow-on naive search. I don't know for sure that it's a naive search, but a flattened string to me implies traversing the `subject_string` step-by-step instead of through a search tree.

And possibly something less than **O(mn)** when the tree-traversal doesn't hit the recursion limit, though I'm not entirely sure what they're gaining by walking the `subject_string` recursively.

For an actual *what is the time complexity for Javascript implementations*, you'll probably want to ask the runtime devs directly or see if what they're doing is like other [string searching algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) to figure out which cases run in what time complexity.

Comment: [Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40612946/1048572) are a whole chapter of V8…

Comment: @Bergi nice! i knew i was in the weeds looking at ConsString, but didn't really know where to look for its definition.

Comment: Another good read on the topic is [this article](http://mrale.ph/blog/2016/11/23/making-less-dart-faster.html) (I didn't find it before as I though it would be on the [V8 blog](https://v8project.blogspot.de/))

Comment: that's good reading. i had a feeling it was a binary tree and binary searching when they started splitting up the ConsString into pairs of recursive branches, but didn't know enough about the "intimidating zoo of different string representations" to really know.