# Java difference in String.replace between java 12 and 13

Tags: java, string, replace, java-13

I noticed a difference in the behaviour of the `String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` between java 12 and 13.

java 12 and earlier:

```
System.out.println("String"=="String".replace("g","g")); //false
```

java 13 and later:

```
System.out.println("String"=="String".replace("g","g")); //true
```

Found that this is probably due to:

[Optimize String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence) for common cases](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8222955)

Is this unexpected behaviour?

Yes, I'm aware of the equals method.

Comment: You have an extra double quote in there.

Comment: I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839#513839 -- you shouldn't compare strings with `==` but use the `equals` method.

Comment: Welcome TitaniumDave. My recommendation to the other #moderators: this question is valid and only should be considered "virtually duplicate" iff you are a java expert and know the answer. Therefore, this question should be opened, and the answer should point to the related answer. There may be other answers in the future in context of the OP well beyond the individual `equals` method.

Comment: A good summary of what has changed in `String.replace` in Java 9-13: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58199878/706317

Comment: Thank you @ZhekaKozlov for providing more context.

Comment: @Todd Thank you. Glad you understood the question to a further extend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API specification makes no guarantees of whether `String.replace` returns a new String object or if it reuses the original when possible. The result of the comparison is "unspecified". That means it may change from one version to the next, just like you've discovered.

Use the .equals method to compare strings for equality.