# String#replaceAll vs StringUtils#replace()

Tags: java, performance, replace

Is there any reason to use `String.replaceAll(String,String)` instead of `StringUtils.replace()` at all?

Assuming both libraries are available and we are not passing in a regex.

From the few previous posts on this topic I see there are multiple tests and benchmarks pointing to that `String.replace` is slow, but I don't recall anyone explaining whether there is a case for using `String.replaceAll` over `StringUtils.replace`

Source for benchmark: [Commons Lang StringUtils.replace performance vs String.replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228992/commons-lang-stringutils-replace-performance-vs-string-replace)

Comment: I think the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012000/apache-stringutils-vs-java-implementation-of-replace) explains it fairly well, and that the comparable option would be `String.replace(char sequence, char sequence)` and not `replaceAll`

Comment: Don’t ignore one of the most important considerations:  dependency on a third-party library makes your program larger and less portable, and subject to that library’s security issues.  And Java SE, while not perfect, has vastly better QA and documentation than any third-party library I have encountered.

Answer (score 5):

`String.replaceAll` and `StringUtils.replace` (assuming Apache Commons here) are two completely different beasts. The former is using a Regular Expression as search term and performs a replacement with support of Regular Expressions as well, the latter is just looking for occurrences of the given text and replaces it by the replacement text.

With `String.replaceAll` you can e.g. do something like this:

```
System.out.println("John Smith".replaceAll("^(\S+)\s*(\S+)\*$", "$2, $1"));
```

which will output

```
Smith, John
```

You can't do that with `StringUtils.replace`.

> Assuming both libraries are available and we are not passing in a regex.

`String.replaceAll` is always parsing the search-term as Regex and performs the replacement assuming it to be using regex-functions as well, so it simply doesn't make sense to use this method without actually using Regex.

If you just want to do a simple text-replacement you just use `String.replace(CharSequence c1, CharSequence c2)` that was added with Java 1.5

> From the few previous posts on this topic I see there are multiple tests and benchmarks pointing to that String.replace

Some sources would be nice, where you've seen that statement. The link Nexevis provided covered Java 1.4 where above method didn't exist and - without doing some tests myself now - I have doubts that the performance between `String.replace(CharSequence...)` and `StringUtils.replace` differ a lot because `StringUtils`' implementation looks quite straight forward and will most likely not differ a lot from the implementation in the JVM. The existence of it is purely historical because of the lack of a similar method in Java Version before 1.5

Comment: iirc String.replace(CharSequence c1, CharSequence c2) is still using the regex pattern compilier which would make it a bit slower. I'll update the post with benchmark sources.