# Where can I access StringUtils.replaceEach()?

Tags: string-utils

The answer to [Java escape HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874626/java-escape-html/4874768#4874768) shows `StringUtils.replaceEach()` which runs similar to multiple `StringUtils.replace()`s, but accepting arrays of `String`s instead of having to do each replace individually.

For example:

```
str = StringUtils.replace(str, "&", "&amp;");
str = StringUtils.replace(str, "\"", "&quot;");
str = StringUtils.replace(str, "<", "&lt;");
str = StringUtils.replace(str, ">", "&gt;");
```

...becomes...

```
str = StringUtils.replaceEach(str,
    new String[]{"&", "\"", "<", ">"},
    new String[]{"&amp;", "&quot;", "&lt;", "&gt;"})
```

Much cleaner.

**Where can I access `StringUtils.replace()`?**

I have tried importing the following, to no avail:

1. `org.springframework.util.StringUtils`
2. `org.apache.soap.util.StringUtils`
3. `org.apache.axis.utils.StringUtils`
4. `com.ibm.wsdl.util.StringUtils`

They each have `.replace()`, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It believe you are looking for: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils

You can find more about it here:

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

And download the .jar here:

http://commons.apache.org/lang/

Comment: thanks so much. Unfortunately I cannot add new `.jar`s to this project as I am not in control of that.