# Replace characters with HTML entities in Java

Tags: html, jakarta-ee, escaping, html-entities

I want to replace certain characters with their respective HTML entities in an HTML response inside a filter. Characters include `<`, `>`, `&`. I can't use `replaceAll()` as it will replace all characters, even those that are part of HTML tags.

What is the best approach for doing so?

Comment: If a single string has already been formed that contains a mixture of HTML tags and standalone characters such as `<`, then it's probably too late. Can you not HTML encode the string *data* before it get's included inside tags?

Comment: My application boundaries doesn't allow me to do it earlier :(

Comment: But just think - if it was *possible* to do this reliably with fully formed strings, you wouldn't *need* to do encoding - web browsers would use whatever this magical technique is to distinguish tags from general text.

Comment: That is what I need to do. so far what i am doing is to traverse the HTML character by character and checking for '<' and '>'. Considering it as tag (ignoring the attributes), I am checking it in pre-defined tag list. If match does not found I am encoding both '<' and '>'. I don't weather it is right approach...

Answer (score 12):

From Java you may try Apache Commons Lang (legacy v2)  [`StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml(java.lang.String)). Or with commons-lang3: [`StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml4(java.lang.String)).

<sup>Please note this also converts `à` to `&agrave;` & such.</sup>

Comment: This is the best, IMHO, the best solution

Comment: Simple, clean and works just fine in Groovy as well.

Comment: Also worth noting: if you're (already) using a web framework, there's a good chance a similar function is already built into the framework.  Spring, for example, has HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(), documented here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/HtmlUtils.html

Comment: `org.apache.commons.lang3` is now deprecated, the replacement is `org.apache.commons.text`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a technology such as JSTL, you can simply print out the value using `<c:out value="${myObject.property}"/>` and it will be automatically escaped.

The attribute `escapeXml` is `true` by default.

> `escapeXml` - Determines whether characters `<,>,&,',"` in the resulting
>   string should be converted to their corresponding character entity
>   codes. Default value is `true`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/

Comment: I have no control over the application before it comes to me as a HTML response.

Answer (score 0):

When developing in Spring ecosystem, one can use `HtmlUtils.htmlEscape()` method.

For full apidocs, visit https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/HtmlUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

Since most solutions reference a deprecated Apache class, here's one I've adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16947646/3196753.

```java
public class StringUtilities {

    public static final String[] HTML_ENTITIES = {"&", "<", ">", "\"", "'", "/"};
    public static final String[] HTML_REPLACED =  {"&amp;", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&quot;", "&apos;", "&sol;"};

    public static String escapeHtmlEntities(String text) {
        return StringUtils.replaceEach(text, HTML_ENTITIES, HTML_REPLACED);
    }
}
```

**Note:** This is not a comprehensive solution (it's not context-aware -- may be too aggressive) but I needed a quick, effective solution.