# Does java have a built in way to convert angle-brackets to entity codes?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommended method for escaping HTML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java)
>   [Replace characters with HTML entities in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978098/replace-characters-with-html-entities-in-java)

I have some java code which writes text including angle-brackets to a DB; this text is displayed on a web-page.

Rather than change my java code to be full of entity codes, I wondered if I can keep the constants like "`<test>`" and use a standard library function to generate the entity-based string "`&lt;test&gt;`"?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978098/replace-characters-with-html-entities-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to do angle brackets, I'd have a look at Java's [String Replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) functionality.

But you probably should take a look at [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)  if you want a more complete solution

in particular, [public static String escapeHtml(String str)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29) looks like a promising function

---

Judging by that signature, I would guess that

```
string myEscapedHTML = escapeHtml(myUnescapedHTML);
```

is the way to use it.