# ÙØ±Ø­Ø¨Ø§ want to know encoding of the characters

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm sending مرحبا characters from JSP to servlet and in servlet i'm receiving the characters in this format ÙØ±Ø­Ø¨Ø§. i want to know which one is converting this and which encoidng they are using.

If i pass these characters in POST Method, i'll receive data as it is.

i'm using JDK 1.6, Tomcat 7.

This is the JSP.

```
<%@page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>Insert title here</title></head><body><form method="get" action="register">
    Name:<input type="text" name="userName"/><br/><br/> 
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form></body></html>
```

This is the servlet.

```
public class Register extends HttpServlet { 
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {     
    try {
        System.out.println("System: file.endcoding=" + System.getProperty("file.encoding"));

        String str= request.getParameter("userName").trim();    
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Display.jsp");
        System.out.println("before encoding and decoding the string : "+str);
        request.setAttribute("beforeconvert",str);}catch(Exception e){}}
```

Comment: File file = new File(str);
InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file));
System.out.println("Encoing of the received string : "+r.getEncoding());

Comment: You'd better post the snippet of your send and receive.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723339/utf-8-encoding-in-jsp-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is more or less an UTF8 encoded string that is decoded as Latin1.

Original string `"مرحبا"` is composed of characters having the following Unicode code points: '0x645', '0x631', '0x62d', '0x628', '0x627'

When encoded as UTF8, it gives: '\xd9\x85\xd8\xb1\xd8\xad\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7' which when interpreted as Latin1 gives: `"ÙØ±Ø­Ø¨Ø§"`. The character `'\x85'` is normally non printable in Latin1. But it is enough for the string you gave in your question to be non decodable as UTF8.

As you say you use a POST method, you should be able to declare in the form that the data will be UTF8 encoded. Normally `<form accept-charset="UTF8" ...>` should be enough

In a GET request, there is no way to specify any encoding. You must decide how you will want to interpret them. You have to ways to do that:

- explicitely at application level:

  ```
  Charset u8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
  Charset l1 = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
  String utf8String = u8.decode(l1.encode(str)).toString();
  ```
- or ask the servlet container to do it for you. For Tomcat, you can set the URIEncoding attribute on the `<Connector>` element in server.xml to the expected charset: `URIEncoding="UTF-8"`.
  [refs](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding)

Comment: why it gets converted like that for GET Request?

Comment: and how to get UTF-8 Characters in Tomcat 7 without adding URI-Encoding in server.xml.

Comment: for GET Request

Comment: That helps a lot, Thanks Serge Ballesta

Comment: Hi Serge Ballesta...   I'm Passing مرحبا character from JSP and in servlet using getParameter i'm capturing value and printing the value.

It is in this format,

'&#1605;&#1585;&#1581;&#1576;&#1575;'
Now i want to convert it into UTF-16 String and store it in DB. And when i retrieve from DB, again i want to convert it to that HTML code.

I'm using JSP and page encoding is ISO-8859-1, Servlet, Tomcat 7 and it is GET Request. Can u help me?

Comment: @GaneshBhagavath: search SO for [java] html entities for more info, but at least those 2 questions should help http://stackoverflow.com/q/994331/3545273 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/10978098/3545273