# Replace special characters with their respective encoding from the list

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

I need to replace special characters with their respective encoding from the list, below are the sample list of characters and their  encoding

```
  '&Aacute;' => 'Á', 
  '&aacute;' => 'á', 
  '&Acirc;' => 'Â', 
  '&acirc;' => 'â', 
  '&acute;' => '´', 
  '&AElig;' => 'Æ', 
  '&aelig;' => 'æ', 
  '&Agrave;' => 'À', 
  '&agrave;' => 'à', 
  '&alefsym;' => 'ℵ', 
  '&Alpha;' => 'Α', 
  '&alpha;' => 'α', 
  '&amp;' => '&', 
  '&and;' => '∧',
```

Source String = `"this is some sample à for character encoding æ"`

After replace character in string should look like below:

output= `"this is some sample &aacute for character encoding &aelig;"`

Comment: [Duplicate ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10978284/6730571)

Comment: @Reimeus i don't this is duplicate?

Comment: i'm voting to reopen this question as not duplicate

Comment: @YCF_L yes it is. did you see the answer about `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml`?

Comment: @Reimeus how it will be duplicate, can you share the link for the solution ?

Comment: @Reimeus this is not about Html, it is about some special characters

Comment: @pankajdesai study the javadoc from the best answer, it does exactly what you want

Comment: @Reimeus there will be some custom codes as well in the list, it is not limited to html code.

Comment: @Reimeus Thanks will look into StringEscapeUtils as well but I hope you able to understand the problem statement

Comment: "HTML" does not appear in the question, but the "encoding" that is requested *is* [HTML entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity), and the question is the same as "how to convert those characters to HTML entities", and the duplicate answers that already.-- But maybe the answer deserves an update, I'll see what I can do about that.