# Stripping out HTML tags from Java string with zero deps

Tags: java, html, regex, string

I understand that this question is *very* similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874626/java-escape-html) and others. I have the same question (**how to strip out HTML tags from a Java string?**) with the *added* constraint that I don't want to add any dependencies (Apache Commons, Spring, etc.) to my code.

So I'm looking for a "pure Java SE" flavor of the HTML tag-stripping algorithms used by a lot of these other frameworks, but not sure exactly where to start. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"..that I don't want to add any dependencies (Apache Commons, Spring, etc.) to my code."*  Look in the `java.magic` package.  Or to put that another way, why do you think there would be so many 3rd party Java based APIs for parsing HTML, if the J2SE had it built in?

Comment: Can't you simulate the accepted solution of the question you refer to by a bunch of `String.replaceAll` calls?

Comment: Escape HTML and stripping HTML tags are different things altogether. Which one do you want to do?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewThompson I just fired up Eclipse and did a search for `java.magic` but do not see anything? Are you sure this ships with the JDK? Thanks again, and +1!

Comment: Thanks @nhahtdh (+1) - I guess I want to *strip* them? And by the way, what *is* the difference? Thanks again!

Comment: `java.magic` - That was *sarcasm..*

Comment: Adding some more details on what Heuster has alreay pointed. Search the string for html tags, replace them with ''. You can maintain a list of all HTML tags in an array, loop through it and call replaceAll for each tag.

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys: Escaping HTML means keeping everything, but you don't want the text to be treated as plain text rather than HTML by a browser/parser. Stripping HTML means you remove all the tags (throw away them all and not recoverable).

Answer (score 0):

Without using the HTMLEditorKit explicitly:

```
    String html = "<html>...";
    JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
    pane.setContentType("text/html");
    pane.setText(html);
    StyledDocument doc = pane.getStyledDocument();
    try {
        System.out.println("Text: " + doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```