# How to make replaceAll working in java?

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I've tried different way but not working yet.

```
public String SuEscapeHTML(String text){
    text=text.replaceAll("/&/g", "&amp;");
    // and how to deal with the double quote? text=text.replaceAll("/"/g", "&quot;");
    text=text.replaceAll("/'/g", "&apos;");
    text=text.replaceAll("/</g", "&lt;");
    text=text.replaceAll("/>/g", "&gt;");
    text=text.replaceAll("/\\/g", "&#92;");
    System.out.println(text);
    return text;
}
```

nothing change by using this function.

So How to make it working?

Comment: You aren't using a regular expression, so use `String.replace`; also there are several libraries that already do this (don't reinvent the wheel).

Comment: See the documentation for `replaceAll`.  It doesn't take `/.../g`

Comment: @chanjianyi have you tried text=text.replaceAll("&", "&amp;")?  (Might want to do that one last)

Comment: what you are using in regex is syntax of javascript..that's not how you write regex in JAVA

Comment: @Slaks is right ... [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/) documentation, btw. (or change it to 7 for jdk 7, or if earlier... shoot yourself)

Comment: I am sure answers in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874626/java-escape-html) can help you.

Comment: @Tibrogargan: If you leave the ampersand for last, it will mess up all the others.  Of course, we're assuming there aren't any HTML escapes in the text already; that's another reason why you should use a dedicated tool for this.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of regex you are using is of JavaScript. This is how you will do it in Java

```
String text = "&>\"<\\'"; //You need to escape " in text also

System.out.println(text.replaceAll("&", "&amp;")); 
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("\"", "&quot;")); //For quotes
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("'", "&apos;"));
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("<", "&lt;"));
System.out.println(text.replaceAll(">", "&gt;"));
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("\\\\", "&#92;"));
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/fDyzOy)**

Comment: The name of the language is Java, not JAVA; it's not an acronym.  Otherwise, good answer.